# Vertically sorted multi-columns with CSS inside a responsive layout

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Is there a working way to use CSS for automatically splitting a sorted list into multiple columns where the content stays sorted vertically? We are using Bootstrap, so any related helper classes could be used. Doesn't have to be a Bootstrap related solution of course.

What we have tried so far:

Bootstrap grid layout
-> works fine in all relevant browsers, but always sorts the content horizontally due to it's floating behaviour

column-count
-> keeps the horizontal sorting, but has many display issues (breaks list items in the middle when they have line breaks inside, many optical interferences even in modern browsers)

Comment: i would recommand using the display flex property with different sizes

Comment: You would need to clarify what you mean by "***stays**  sorted vertically*". In particular, what does "*stays*" mean in this context? Can you provide three schemas for mobile/tablet/desktop sorting/layout order rules?

Comment: "Stays" just means that the data source (list) is sorted alphabetically from top to bottom and should be displayed this way. So the columns content should be read from top to bottom and not from left to right (which is the case when using a floating grid layout).

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be looking for [CSS Multi-column Layout Module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns). Assuming you'll just add a `columns` class to some `.row`:

```
.row.columns {
  columns: 3; 
  /* change number of columns according to needs using `@media` queries */
}
```

To prevent `.col-*`children from from breaking across multiple columns

```
.columns > [class*="col-"] {
  break-inside: avoid;
  width: 100%;
  float: none;
}
```

For maximum browser compatibility, use [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/) with `> 0%` in "Filter" box (left bottom corner).

Proof of concept:

```css
.row.columns {
  columns: 3; 
}
.columns > [class*="col-"] {
  break-inside: avoid;
  width: 100%;
  float: none;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .row.columns {
    columns: 2; 
  }
}

@media (max-width: 479px) {
  .row.columns {
    columns: 1; 
  }
}
```

Fully prefixed, working snippet:

```css
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

body {
    margin: 0;
}
.row.columns {
  -webkit-columns: 3;
     -moz-columns: 3;
          columns: 3; 
  padding-top: 15px;
}
.row.columns > *:first-child > *:first-child{
  margin-top: 0;
}

.columns > [class*="col-"] {
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
     page-break-inside: avoid;
          break-inside: avoid;
  width: 100%;
  float: none;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .row.columns {
    -webkit-columns: 2;
       -moz-columns: 2;
            columns: 2; 
  }
}
@media (max-width: 479px) {
  .row.columns {
    -webkit-columns: 1;
       -moz-columns: 1;
            columns: 1; 
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row columns">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h2>1. HTML</h2>
            <p>HTML is a markup language that is used for creating web pages. The HTML tutorial section will help you understand the basics of HTML, so that you can create your own web pages or website.</p>
            <p><a href="https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/" target="_blank" class="btn btn-success">Learn More &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h2>2. CSS</h2>
            <p>CSS is used for describing the presentation of web pages. The CSS tutorial section will help ou learn the essentials of CSS, so that you can fine control the style and layout of your HTML document.</p>
            <p>This is an extra paragraph added so the elements have different height. This is an extra paragraph added so the elements have different height. This is an extra paragraph added so the elements have different height.</p>
            <p><a href="https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-tutorial/" target="_blank" class="btn btn-success">Learn More &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h2>3. Bootstrap</h2>
            <p>Bootstrap is a powerful front-end framework for faster and easier web development. The Bootstrap tutorial section will help you learn the techniques of Bootstrap so that you can create web your own website.</p>
            <p><a href="https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/" target="_blank" class="btn btn-success">Learn More &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h2>4. CSS</h2>
            <p>CSS is used for describing the presentation of web pages. The CSS tutorial section will help ou learn the essentials of CSS, so that you can fine control the style and layout of your HTML document.</p>
            <p><a href="https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-tutorial/" target="_blank" class="btn btn-success">Learn More &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h2>5. HTML</h2>
            <p>HTML is a markup language that is used for creating web pages. The HTML tutorial section will help you understand the basics of HTML, so that you can create your own web pages or website.</p>
            <p><a href="https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/" target="_blank" class="btn btn-success">Learn More &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h2>6. Bootstrap</h2>
            <p>Bootstrap is a powerful front-end framework for faster and easier web development. The Bootstrap tutorial section will help you learn the techniques of Bootstrap so that you can create web your own website.</p>
            <p><a href="https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/" target="_blank" class="btn btn-success">Learn More &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h2>7. HTML</h2>
            <p>HTML is a markup language that is used for creating web pages. The HTML tutorial section will help you understand the basics of HTML, so that you can create your own web pages or website.</p>
            <p><a href="https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/" target="_blank" class="btn btn-success">Learn More &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h2>8. Bootstrap</h2>
            <p>Bootstrap is a powerful front-end framework for faster and easier web development. The Bootstrap tutorial section will help you learn the techniques of Bootstrap so that you can create web your own website.</p>
            <p><a href="https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/" target="_blank" class="btn btn-success">Learn More &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was trying with column-count (columns is just shorthand for it as I understand it) and media queries before, I just missed the break-inside option. I will try this tomorrow and flag your answer appropriately. Thanks so far, looks promising.

Comment: Tested and works fine. And thanks for mentioning Autoprefixer with "> 0%" filter. :)

Comment: I have to revert my solution flag. "break-inside: avoid" could be the solution, but it's basically not supported by browsers right now: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/break-inside#Browser_compatibility (resulting in an optically clustered list which is splitting items right in the middle, e.g. in Firefox).

Comment: @drakanor, upon testing, it looks like the reason why it doesn't work in FF is not related to `break-inside`, but to not resetting float on `.col-*`s. I updated the solution. It works in my FF, on Linux. I'm assuming it works in others as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this didn't help for my case in Firefox. I have list items with padding and borders, and Firefox ist still splitting them wrongly. But I found a solution that is working so far. Instead of using "break-inside: avoid", Firefox is accepting "page-break-inside: avoid". Using this option everything seems to work fine so far. I'm using these options now:

-webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
page-break-inside: avoid;
break-inside: avoid;

Comment: Where exactly did you find that solution, @drakanor? Because it's been part of my answer since the very beginning. Just press "Show code snippet" link and you'll see it. If, for any reason, my solution doesn't apply to your project, you should add a [mcve] to your question to make sure I can test against whatever you have.